# How to pass union types through Elm ports?

Tags: json, elm

I've bumped into an issue while trying out Elm. I want to pass a union type through a port but I get this error:

```
Port `setStorage` is trying to communicate an unsupported type.

34| port setStorage : Model -> Cmd msg
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The specific unsupported type is:

    Todo.Importance

The types of values that can flow through in and out of Elm include:

    Ints, Floats, Bools, Strings, Maybes, Lists, Arrays,
    Tuples, Json.Values, and concrete records.
```

I've modified the Todo [example](https://github.com/evancz/elm-todomvc/blob/master/Todo.elm) as follows:

```
type alias Task =
    { description : String
    , completed : Bool
    , editing : Bool
    , id : Int
    , importance : Importance -- <- this is the new field
    }

type Importance
  = Normal
  | High
  | Low
```

This [issue](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/490) appears to be quite old. One commenter suggests to "pass Json.Values through ports and Json.Decode/Encode them" but how exactly to do that? The documentation appears a bit unclear and lacks full examples. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've made it [work](https://github.com/nikoudel/elm-todomvc/commit/9f9e8cfb2cb8d5ce31ef6f6b2a96d6368a308b66) with Json.Decoder/Encoder. Wasn't that difficult after all although having to serialize every single field just to pass that one union type is quite a burden.

Decoders:

```
modelDecoder : Json.Decoder Model
modelDecoder =
  Json.object4 Model
    ("tasks" := Json.list taskDecoder)
    ("field" := Json.string)
    ("uid" := Json.int)
    ("visibility" := Json.string)

taskDecoder : Json.Decoder Task
taskDecoder =
  Json.object5 Task
    ("description" := Json.string)
    ("completed" := Json.bool)
    ("editing" := Json.bool)
    ("id" := Json.int)
    ("importance" := Json.string `andThen` importanceDecoder)

importanceDecoder : String -> Json.Decoder Importance
importanceDecoder tag =
  case tag of
    "Normal" -> Json.succeed Normal
    "High" -> Json.succeed High
    "Low" -> Json.succeed Low
    _ -> Json.fail (tag ++ " is not a recognized tag for Importance")
```

And encoders:

```
modelToValue : Model -> Json.Encode.Value
modelToValue model =
  Json.Encode.object
    [
      ("tasks", Json.Encode.list (List.map taskToValue model.tasks)),
      ("field", Json.Encode.string model.field),
      ("uid", Json.Encode.int model.uid),
      ("visibility", Json.Encode.string model.visibility)
    ]

taskToValue : Task -> Json.Encode.Value
taskToValue task =
  Json.Encode.object
    [
      ("description", Json.Encode.string task.description),
      ("completed", Json.Encode.bool task.completed),
      ("editing", Json.Encode.bool task.editing),
      ("id", Json.Encode.int task.id),
      ("importance", importanceToValue task.importance)
    ]

importanceToValue : Importance -> Json.Encode.Value
importanceToValue importance =
  case importance of
    Normal -> Json.Encode.string "Normal"
    High -> Json.Encode.string "High"
    Low -> Json.Encode.string "Low"
```

Comment: This feature won't be implemented anytime soon... over on Elm Slack @rtfeldman says this feature is way down on the priority list and that he would be surprised if it happened in the next year. That was as of May 23, 2017.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass a union type above all because JS does not know about such a thing. So you might as well pass a string and do a case statement in javascript - I do it all the time.